# Emphasizing a string in code example using showexpl

Tags: listings, highlighting, showexpl

I am writing documentation for a package using the showexpl package which in turn uses the listings package. When using listing I can highlight a portion of the code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  moredelim=[is][\color{red}]{<}{>}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  This is an <emphasized string>.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

But passing the `moredelim` option to a `LTXexample` environment does not have the desired effect, the code remains black.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  moredelim=[is][\color{red}]{<}{>}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{LTXexample}
  This is an <emphasized string>.
\end{LTXexample}


\end{document}
```

Is there something I am missing about passing the `moredelim` option to the `LTXexample` environment correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use moredelim the delimiter are stripped already from the code when showexpl *writes* the code to a temporary file. (Check the tmp-file). So when the listing is printed the delimiters are simply not there. You can avoid it by using explpreset (don't use both  moredelim and explpreset this leads to confusion.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\lstset{
% moredelim=[is][\color{red}]{:}{.}
 explpreset={moredelim={[is][\color{red}]{:}{.}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  This is an :emphasized string.
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{LTXexample}
  This is an :emphasized string.
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

you'll get problems with frames when using a different color:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showexpl}
    \lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  explpreset={moredelim=[is][\color{red}]{<}{>}}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\catcode`\<=\active \def<{}
\catcode`\>=\active \def>{}
\begin{LTXexample}
  This is an <emphasized string>.
\end{LTXexample}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to remove the brackets from the compiled example?

Comment: no, showexpl shows the LaTeX output and not the one from listings

Comment: Are there any other options, save for having the code appear twice in the document (once in a listing and once typeset)?

Comment: @Nickolay: To remove the brackets from the output you can make them active and define them to do nothing: `\catcode`\<=\active \def<{}`. Do it before the example and put a group around this definition and the example.

Comment: @Ulrike: I added it to the example

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ulrike! Doing this only once in the preamble would be nice though, as I have a lot of examples. Can I define a macro which would take care of the `\catcode` invocations and the grouping?